# JS countdown to order before 5pm, issue with other 3pm products

Tags: javascript, function, countdown

Hi im building a site with a delivery countdown in JS (Order in the next 5 hrs 58 mins for delivery by Wednesday). 
5pm is the default but some product ranges need it to be order at 3pm the div that contains these products is "supplier_1010".

the part with this code doesnt seem to find div with class supplier_1010 and change the timer.

https://jsfiddle.net/iangerdes/eqc6jsho/127/ has example of this.

html

```
<div class="product">
<div class="timer"></div>  
</div>
<div class="product">
<div class="timer"></div>  
</div>
<div class="product">
<div class="timer"></div>  
</div>
<div class="product supplier_1010">
<div class="timer "></div>  
</div>
<div class="product supplier_1010">
<div class="timer"></div>  
</div>
<div class="product">
<div class="timer"></div>  
</div>
```

JS

THIS bit doesnt work.

```
if ($this.find('.supplier_1010').length > 0) {

      start.setHours(14, 45, 0); // 14.45
  }
```

JS

```
$('.product').each(function() { 
  var $this = $(this);
  var countdown = setInterval(function() { 


     var start = new Date();
     var now = new Date();
     var weekday = now.getDay();

   var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var deliverydate = days[start.getDay() +1 ];

 if ($this.find('.supplier_1010').length > 0) {

      start.setHours(14, 45, 0); // 14.45
  }

  else { 
  start.setHours(17, 0, 0); // 5.00
  }





  if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
       deliverydate = days[now.getDay() +2 ];
      } 



    var Today = start.getDate();
    var Month = start.getMonth();


    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);  
    var hh = Math.floor((remain / 60 / 60) % 60); 
    var mm = Math.floor((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = Math.floor(remain % 60);


  var timertext ='<i class="fa fa-truck"></i>' + 'Order in the next ' + '<strong>' + hh + ' hrs ' + mm + ' mins ' + ss + '</strong>'+ ' for delivery  by '+ deliverydate + '<a href="#" class="small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDelivery">' + ' * See Exceptions'+ '</a>';



   jQuery(".timer").html(''+ timertext +'');



  }, 1000); 


  });
```

any help would be great. its probably really simple but can't figure it out!!

cheers Ian

Answer (score 0):

`.find(selector)` will "Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element." [`.find` docs](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Your `.each` loop goes through each `.product` div. For each div, it looks for a *descendant* with the class `supplier_1010`, but in no case in your HTML is a `.supplier_1010` a descendant of a `.product`.

Instead of

- `if ($this.find('.supplier_1010').length > 0) {`

you could try

- `$this.hasClass('supplier_1010')`

You are really wanting to find the case where the div you are looping over *itself* has the `supplier_1010` class (see [`.hasClass` docs](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)).

EDIT---

In addition,

- `jQuery(".timer").html(''+ timertext +'');`

at the end should be updated to:

- `jQuery($this).find(".timer").html(''+ timertext +'');` => this way it updates each *individual* timer with `timertext` rather than all of the timers.

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9zpw43v/1/

Comment: thanks thmsdnnr but doesnt seem to be working for me. ill have a crack tomorrow. many thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @IanGerdes I found one additional issue at the end there: I updated my post with details and linked to a (I believe) working fiddle of what you're going for.